# Trying to use map() in TypeScript with a get-or-default statement

Tags: typescript

Essentially, I want to use .map() on a dictionary to perform a statement on each element in a specific key. The statement itself is that I need to go username by username and check it in a different array and:
- if the username exists there, to record a value contained in the array;
- else, to record 0;

Alright, first of all, thanks in advance for tour help!

Second, you need to know my background is in data analysis, not programming and I normally use Python but for this, I'm working with the IT Team Lead and he insisted on TypeScript, so here we are.

Essentially I have the following objects:
1. Dictionary allEntries: {
    valid: boolean;
    user: string;
2. Another dictionary, containing the array intUsernames: string[][] and the stakes: [] which we're looking to record, where applicable

I need to iterate over allEntries, to check if each of the usernames in intUsernames is in there and if it is, to record its corresponding "stakes" value; else, to record 0.

```
 let values = allEntries.map(element => intUsernames[element.user] || 0);
```

But then I realised this might not work, as I need to access my stakes value for each entry, so I tried:

```
  let values = [];
  for (let entry of allEntries) {
    if (entry.user !in result.interestingUsers) {
      values.fill("0")
    }
    else {
      values.fill(result.interestingUsers.map(function (userEntry){ return [userEntry.stakes]}))
  };
```

Expected an array[][] of values, either [0] or a natural number. However, with the first method, I get an array of only [0], whereas with the second, I get an empty array[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this do what you want?

```
const allEntries = [{ user: "foo", stake: 500 }, { user: "bar", stake: 100 }];
const result = {
  interestingUsers: ["foo"]
};

const values = [];

allEntries.forEach((entry, index) => {
  const found = result.interestingUsers.find(el => entry.user === el);
  values[index] = found ? entry.stake : 0;
});

console.log(values); // [ 'foo', 0 ]
```

---

Although I'm not sure how you intend to implement this, I think, however, it might be a better idea not to create a new array with only values, it'll be hard to keep track of which "stake" is of which "user".

It might be better to do this:

```
const allEntries = [{ username: "foo", stake: 500 }, { username: "bar", stake: 100 }];
const result = { interestingUsers: ["foo"] };

const filteredUsers = allEntries.filter(entry => result.interestingUsers.includes(entry.username))


console.log(filteredUsers); // [ { username: "foo", stake: 500 }, 0 ]
```

Please note that for `.includes` to work you might have to make sure that in your tsconfig.json you set `compilerOptions.target = 2016` to

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer!

It now returns an array of either "0" or the actual username, not the stake value associated with the username.

I'll update you if I make it work!

Comment: how about this?